# Oracle APEX changing the colour of display only item with PL/SQL query

Tags: html, css, sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a display only item in a static content which looks like this:

[image]

I want to change the whole background colour of the button/item instead of the text's colour.

My PL/SQL code looks like this for example for the first item:

```
SELECT case ACTUAL_SITUATION when 'Y' then '<span style="color:green">Yes</span>'
                          when 'N' then '<span style="color:red">No</span>' end as "ACTUAL_SITUATION "
FROM tableName
```

Is it possible to change it with PL/SQL? All I could do is change the span background colour and that was just a highlight on the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a "Display Only" field, set the "Source" to be a "SQL Query(return single value)" and be sure to set under "Security", "Escape special characters" to "No" to allow the HTML to flow through.  Note that you want to use `background-color` not `color` in your style to set the [background](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-color.asp).

I tested it and it works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried it but it only highlighted the "Yes" or "No". What I need is to change the whole background colour of the dashed line area. I managed it somehow with CSS (with inscept element so I could see which CSS is it) - but I don't know how to make work regarding to the SQL query. I mean it should display colour red or green depending the answer is Yes or No.

Comment: Thanks for the details.  Images on Stack Exchanged are blocked at my work (!) so I didn't see the image; sorry.  I should have looked before I answered. Glad you got it solved.

Comment: I still could not solve it in a proper way because for some reason I cannot access that Apex's CSS with the PL\SQL query - only the colour of the characters.